# Перенос строки в document.write

Tags: javascript

Почему перенос строки `\n` не работает в `document.write`?

```js
document.write("lalala \n lalala");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Потому что браузер игнорирует переносы, табы, множ. пробелы и прочие спецсимволы во время прорисовки страницы.

Решение 1

```
document.write ("lalala <br \/> lalala");
```

Решение 2

```
document.write ("<pre>lalala \n lalala<\/pre>");
```

Comment: А в случае если в document.write, помимо строки есть и другие типы данных, например значения переменных, просто использовать +"<br />"+ или + "<pre>"+, или для таких случаев есть другой метод?

Comment: А что вы понимаете под "другим типом данных". Документ - это текст - все что в нем - это текст, `.write` пишет текст. Любые значения javascript приведет в текстовый формат когда их будут выводить в документ

Comment: Всё верно, юзайте +"<br \/>"+ и "<pre>"++"</\pre>". Для произвольной строки можно выполнить замену переносов \n на <br> с помощью метода replace. Но лучшее решение, все же, окружить её <pre>.

Answer (score 2):

Он работает. Но браузер по умолчанию группирует все пробельные символы в один пробел. Надо немого изменить css, чтобы получилось то, что ты хочешь:

```js
document.write("lalala \n lalala");
```

```css
body { white-space: pre-line; }
```